# Content editor missing on some pages Dynamics portal

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, portal, adxstudio-portals

On some pages, the content editor toolbar is missing so I cannot add child files to it for adding a css theme for example. I have added an access rule to the page with a web role of Administrator which is a role that I have as a user, in order to modify the content but still there is no content editor toolbar.

[image]

Is there something more to do ?

Comment: As long as your authenticated and you have the right access control rules, you should see the editor widget. All child pages will also inherit the privilege. Have you tried clearing the cache @ '/_services/about'

Comment: @RedCrusador thanks, just found out that a portal restart is needed to apply the access rule on a page...